# Is it possible to read .so file in Android?

Tags: android

I am new to Android and I have one project which contains an `.so` file. In one `.java` file, this lib is used and I want to read that `.so` file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to put the .so file in the lib folder. Then access it using the demo function as shown below:

```
public static boolean loadNativeLibrary() {

    try {

        Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to load library: " + LIBRARY_NAME);
        System.loadLibrary(LIBRARY_NAME);

    } catch (Exception e) { 
        Log.i(TAG, "Exception loading native library: " + e.toString());
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: @JK thnx for reply,but my mean to say how to convert .so file,so that i am able to read tht file.I not want to know how to use it.

Answer (score 4):

You can't really "read" a .so file; it's a compiled binary that contains machine code. It's not really possible to edit it.

You can list the symbols in it though, for example:

```
android-ndk-r6b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm ./path/to/libfoo.so
```

Comment: in this case i get in cmd "fileName.so" is not an ordinary file? have you any other solution for this

Comment: @Deepak What kind of file is it then? Can you try "ls -l" or "file" on it?

Comment: its android .so file. which is made after compilation of c source code. it want to read the contents of .so file in some readable format.

Answer (score 2):

yes you can. You will need hex editor to read that. Because, as far as I understand, `.so` is just like `.dll` in windows.

Comment: if you want to use it, you could utilize @Jaydeep's answer. If you want to see it's contents. Open it up using hex editor.

Answer (score 0):

Actually inside your  JNI folder, android NDK which convert your native code like c or c++ into binary compiled code that is called "filename.so".You cannot read the binary code .so it wil create lib folder inside your libs/armeabi/ filename.so file.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can read.*.so files.  for this you need a Linux base Computer,  & you need leafpad   with this you can view the *.so file the most readable view to read,  It will happen if you use leafpad  on Linux or Notepad++.
Have a try.
Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can read it using ReadElf.java. 
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/17fcb6c/libs/deviceutil/src/android/cts/util/ReadElf.java.

Below code is reading .SO file and finding out the architecture type.

Complete Code- https://github.com/robust12/ArchFinderBLStack.git

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private final String TAG = "MainActivity";

private final String ARMV7ABI = "armeabi-v7a";
private final String X86 = "x86";
private final String MIPS = "mips";
private final String X86_64 = "x86_64";
private final String ARM64_V8 = "arm64-v8a";
private final String ARMABI = "armeabi";
private String result = "";

private File[] libFilesArray;
private int request_code = 1;
HashMap<Integer, String> typeMap;
private TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
    typeMap = new HashMap<>();
    initializeMap();
    readFilesFromStorage();
    textView.setText(result);
    textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
}
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
private void readFilesFromStorage() throws NullPointerException {
    String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test-input/";
    File readSOFILE = new File(filePath);
    if(!readSOFILE.exists()) {
        result = getString(R.string.path_not_exist);
        return;
    }
    libFilesArray = readSOFILE.listFiles();
    if(libFilesArray == null) {
        result = getString(R.string.error);
        return;
    }
    findAbiType();
}

private void findAbiType() {
    int count = libFilesArray.length;
    int soCount = 0;
    result = "";
    Log.e(TAG, "Count  is  " + count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        try {
            if (libFilesArray[i].isFile()) {
                int type = ReadElf.read(libFilesArray[i]).getType();
                if (type == 3) {
                    soCount++;
                    int archCode = ReadElf.e_machine;
                    result += libFilesArray[i].getName() + " - " + typeMap.get(archCode) + "\n\n";
                    Log.e(TAG, "Code  is  " + archCode);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if(soCount != 0) {
        result += "Total Libs Count: " + soCount + "\n\n";
    } else{
        result = getString(R.string.incorrect_type_libs);
    }
}

private void initializeMap() {
    typeMap.put(40, ARMV7ABI);
    typeMap.put(3, X86);
    typeMap.put(8, MIPS);
    typeMap.put(62, X86_64);
    typeMap.put(183, ARM64_V8);
    typeMap.put(164, ARMABI);
}
```

}

Comment: Please add the relevant code in answer. It will preserve the code in case the file or link stopped working.

Comment: I have edited the answer with code and sample android app GitHub link.